# Maven deploy artifact war from repository to remote server

Tags: maven-2, repository, deployment

I have a build process after which I upload my war to our local Maven repository.

When we deploy to TEST and PROD, I would like to use maven cargo plugin and specify the version to deploy to these environments. How can I configure my pom ( or maybe a new pom called pom-deploy.xml) to pull a particular war from the repository and deploy it remotely?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the WAR file in your new project just declare a dependency for it.

Comment: From what I understand, the question is how to deploy to an app server a war that is in a Maven repository, not how to include a war in another project. Or could you precise your answer ?

Comment: @Guillaume: That's also my understanding of the question. You can found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293741