# Download WAR from snapshot-repository and deploy to local JBoss using mvn

Tags: java, deployment, maven, jboss

currently I deploy my `war` with `jboss:hard-deploy` to my JBoss 6 AS. This works fine, but I have to checkout project from SVN and package it.

The `war` is already uploaded to our internal snapshot repository by Jenkins and it would be nice if I can download it on a testing server from this repository and directly deploy it to JBoss using maven.

This question is related to [Maven deploy artifact war from repository to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/972993), but I don't think the answer is correct (see the comment there).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ideally you would want to set up Jenkins to deploy to your testing server as part of your CI build.

Alternatively, if you want to manually run a script on the server you are deploying to, you could set up a specific `pom.xml` to perform this task. First setup the dependency plugin to download your war:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
              <groupId>my-group</groupId>
              <artifactId>my-web-archive</artifactId>
              <version>my-vesion</version>
              <type>war</type>
              <destFileName>my-web-archive.war</destFileName>
            </artifactItem>
          </artifactItems>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Substituting the group ID, artifact ID and version for the respective properties of your WAR file. Next configure the JBoss plugin to deploy the downloaded WAR:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <jbossHome>/opt/jboss-6</jbossHome>
      <serverName>all</serverName>
      <fileName>${project.build.directory}/my-web-archive.war</fileName>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

You should then be able to download the artifact from your internal repository and deploy it in the locally running JBoss container with the following command:

```
mvn package jboss:hard-deploy
```