# Download war file from nexus with maven

Tags: maven, download, war, nexus

If I have the artifactId, the groupId and the version how I can configure the pom.xml so maven will download test.war file from the nexus repository.
I assume that this should happened in the

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            .....
            </plugin>
```

In the execution block.
I already tried this but no luck:

```
    <execution>
    <phase>package</phase>
    <goals>
        <goal>copy</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
            <artifactItem>
                <artifactId>mytest</artifactId>
                <groupId>com.mytest</groupId>
                <version>${version}</version>
                <type>war</type>
                <destFileName>mytest-${version}.war</destFileName>
            </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download WAR from snapshot-repository and deploy to local JBoss using mvn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293741/download-war-from-snapshot-repository-and-deploy-to-local-jboss-using-mvn)

Comment: I tried this but it did not work!

Comment: then please post what you actually tried so that we can narrow down the troubleshooting, also a bit more details on what's the goal of this copy (other plugins/procedures involved?) would help

Comment: I update the question :)

Comment: The war you are copying, is it actually coming from the same project? I mean, is it actually the one the project is generiting? Also, what didn't work? what error did you get?

Comment: I do not have an error that is why I did not say anything about erros
The war file is on the nexus server and it is build from another project
The idea is that I want to download it with maven using the pom.xml
This will be used in a jenkins job.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118223/discussion-between-a-di-matteo-and-jordan-borisov).

Comment: I do not have access to the chat

Comment: ouch! ok.. and how are you invoking maven? mvn package or mvn dependency:copy?

Comment: clean install from the STS eclipse

Comment: ok, last (hopefully) question:) is the plugin above configured within the `build`/`plugins` section or `build`/`pluginManagement` section?

Comment: in the plugin section

Comment: Interesting. And via the build output (even adding `-X` debug info) the plugin is correctly invoked `[INFO] maven-dependency-plugin:2.10:copy (default-copy) etc.` and no further hints are provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you certain that `${version}` is being set properly for you?  If you need the version of the current project, you should probably be using `<version>${project.version}</version>` and possibly setting up `<dependencyManagement/>` to handle that for you.